# How to calculate right total amount by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have to calculate total amount by using below code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px solid black">
<tr>
<td>Quantity :</td><td><input type="text" id="qty"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rate  :</td><td><input type="text" id="rate"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Discount :</td><td><input type="text" id="dis"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>VAt :</td><td><input type="text" id="vat" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total :</td><td> <input type="text" id="total_amount"></td>
</tr>

</table>
<script>
function calCulate(){
    qty = $('#qty').val();
    rate = $('#rate').val();
    dis = $('#dis').val();
    if(!dis) 
        dis = 0;
    vat = $('#vat').val();  
    total = parseInt((qty * rate) - dis) + parseInt(vat);
    $('#total_amount').val(total);

}

</script>
```

It gives me right amount but after calculation if I change any amount other then vat my total amount not changing because script is not written for that. How can I do an update if any variable gets changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you just need to attach the function logic to the `change` event of all the `input` elements.

A much better way to do this would be to use unobtrusive event handlers instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. As you've already included jQuery, you can use that.

Also note that you should ideally use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert the strings returned from `val()` to numerical values. Try this:

```js
$('#qty, #rate, #dis, #vat').change(function() { // or use a common class
  qty = parseInt($('#qty').val(), 10);
  rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
  dis = parseFloat($('#dis').val() || 0);
  vat = parseFloat($('#vat').val());
  total = parseFloat((qty * rate) - dis) + parseInt(vat);
  $('#total_amount').val(total || 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td>Quantity :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="qty"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rate :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rate"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Discount :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="dis"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VAt :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="vat"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total_amount"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. such an great answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function calCulate(){
    qty = parseInt($('#qty').val());
    rate = parseInt($('#rate').val());
    dis = parseInt($('#dis').val());
    if(!dis) 
        dis = 0;
    vat = parseInt($('#vat').val());  
    total = ((qty * rate) - dis) + vat;
    $('#total_amount').val(total);

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px solid black">
<tr>
<td>Quantity :</td><td><input type="text" id="qty" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rate  :</td><td><input type="text" id="rate" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Discount :</td><td><input type="text" id="dis" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>VAt :</td><td><input type="text" id="vat" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total :</td><td> <input type="text" id="total_amount"></td>
</tr>

</table>
<script>
function calCulate(){
     qty = parseInt($('#qty').val(), 10);
  rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
  dis = parseFloat($('#dis').val() || 0);
  vat = parseFloat($('#vat').val());
  total = parseFloat((qty * rate) - dis) + parseInt(vat);
  $('#total_amount').val(total || 0);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can do like this

```js
<script>
function calCulate(){
    total = 0;
    qty = $('#qty').val();
    rate = $('#rate').val();
    dis = $('#dis').val();
    if(!dis) 
        dis = 0;
    if(!rate) 
        rate = 0;
    if(!qty) 
        qty = 0;
    vat = $('#vat').val();  
    if(!vat) 
        vat = 0;
    total = parseInt((qty * rate) - dis) + parseInt(vat);
    $('#total_amount').val(total);

}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px solid black">
<tr>
<td>Quantity :</td><td><input type="text" id="qty" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rate  :</td><td><input type="text" id="rate" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Discount :</td><td><input type="text" id="dis" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>VAt :</td><td><input type="text" id="vat" onchange="calCulate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total :</td><td> <input type="text" id="total_amount"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

You can call global function on each field so changing any value its re-calculate the total amount.

Answer (score 1):

Give all your `input` fields the same `class`, and then use `.change()` to detect any change to any of these input fields and execute your calculation function.

```js
$('.input').change(function() {
  qty = $('#qty').val();
  rate = $('#rate').val();
  dis = $('#dis').val();
  if (!dis)
    dis = 0;
  vat = $('#vat').val();
  total = parseInt((qty * rate) - dis) + parseInt(vat);
  $('#total_amount').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td>Quantity :</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input" id="qty"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rate :</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input" id="rate"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Discount :</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input" id="dis"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VAT :</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input" id="vat"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total :</td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="input" id="total_amount"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input").on("input",calCulate)// sisnce you have the function call the function on input on input


function calCulate() {
  qty = $('#qty').val();
  rate = $('#rate').val();
  dis = $('#dis').val();
  if (!dis)
    dis = 0;
  vat = $('#vat').val();
  total = parseInt((qty * rate) - dis) + parseInt(vat);
  $('#total_amount').val(total);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td>Quantity :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="qty"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rate :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rate"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Discount :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="dis"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VAt :</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="vat"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total :</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="total_amount"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Call the function that you have now on input/type on input/text

Answer (score 1):

You can try my demo, hope this can help!

[demo](http://jsbin.com/rumiqupupu/edit?html,js,output)

--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', 'input',  calCulate);
});

function calCulate(){
    qty = $('#qty').val();
    rate = $('#rate').val();
    dis = $('#dis').val();
    if(!dis) 
        dis = 0;
    vat = $('#vat').val();  
    total = parseInt((qty * rate) - dis) + parseInt(vat);
    $('#total_amount').val(total||0);
}
```